# Building cross platform apps with access to a database

Tags: javascript, database, wcf, cordova, cross-platform

We need technology or set of technologies to create a cross platform access to a single database. We will create a web application using ASP.NET MVC, deploy mobile applications using PhoneGap, C# for Windows, native for Mac, or AdobeAIR to target Windows, Mac and Linux simultaneously. We need a way to have one centralized access layer so we could make request and get back results from our database.

Is there any way to use WCF service and be secure so only the logged user have access to its data? If not what could be recommended in such scenarios. Note that we need to use JavaScript AJAX request in order to access data when implementing the web and PhoneGap applications.

We will be very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the logged user have access to its data"? You have to implement the Authentication yourself using WCF. It is possible to wrap the data in SOAP and been used by other frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, if you compare this with a portal like twitter or facebook, they very much do what you say. Put OAuth in place for authentication, and identify each HTTP request with the token & key and make the data very much specific to the logged in user.

Doing it this way will let you expand the scope of your platform to provide developer APIs in future if required.